# UITableViewCell display image but not text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` which contains an `UIImageView` and two `UILabel`. When, I run the app, `UIImageVIew` get displayed but not `UILabel`.

Here is my Code:

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.myTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.myTableView.delegate = self;

   titleLabel = @[@"Kiruba",@"Kiruba",@"Kiruba",@"Kiruba"];
   subtitleLabel = @[@"xxx",@"xxx",@"CHN",@"CHN"];
 }

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return titleLabel.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *cellId = @"Cell";
     CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (cell) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }
    //  NSLog(@"Text : %@",[titleLabel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    cell.TitleLabel.text = [titleLabel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.SubtitleLabel.text = [subtitleLabel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DSCN5478.JPG"]

    return cell;
}
```

**CustomCell.h** :

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *SubtitleLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView;
```

Any idea, Why the `UIImageView` get displayed but not `UILabel`?

I'm using Xcode 5 and set target IOS version as 7.

Comment: Is this your real code? I just wonder because `if (cell)` should be `if (cell == nil)`. Or do you use prototype cells?

Comment: @MartinR : I'm using prototype cells

Comment: Then `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` always returns a cell and the following if-statement is not needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Add your `UILabel` and `UIImageView` to the contentView of your custom `UITableViewCell`.